# Resolved: How to exclude specific attributes's values products in category product listing page?

Tags: magento2, filter, listing

I want to exclude product who has specific attributes in category product listing page.

I have created one attribute `product_disble_listing`. if `product_disble_listing` set yes to product that product not show in listing page. override below block in custom module.

```
Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
```

and I have added below code in custom module.

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('product_disble_listing', array('neq' => 1));
```

product collection show correctly but product count, pagination, price filter, color attributes are showing wrong data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it. I have added just below code.

```
$this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('product_disble_listing', array('neq' => 1));
$this->_productCollection->getSize();


return $this->_productCollection;
```

And data showing correct.